# CouchDB and Couchbase Document Keys

Tags: couchdb, couchbase

In reference material for CouchDB and Couchbase it's common guidance to store the `type` of a document as a parameter within the actual document.

I've got a database, where I have different documents that record certain behaviour by URL. So naturally, I use the URL as the id of the document.

The problem I find is that by using just the key as the document id, I now get clashes between documents of different types. So I have started using the type as the first part of the key like this:

```
 { doc._id: "rss_entry|http://www.spiegel.de/1234", [...] }
 { doc._id: "page_text|http://www.spiegel.de/1234", [...] }
```

Now I start to wonder why I've never seen this approach to model type in any of the documentation.

Comment: might be interesting read https://blog.couchbase.com/key-pattern-delimiter-in-couchbase/ why to use :: (double colons) as separator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefixes are commonly used.  In addition to support for scenarios such as yours, prefixing allows one to perform logical range queries against views.  There is use of this technique in the modeling examples, but perhaps the concept is not described in as much detail as you are expecting.  In the section http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-devguide-2.5/#modeling-documents, the documents are keyed as beer_NNNN and brewery_NNNN.  Also, the section http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-devguide-2.5/#using-reference-documents-for-lookups goes a bit deeper into this technique.  There is a counter document named user::count and then each user is keyed as user::NNNN.  Additionally, there are documents in the example that are keyed as fb::NNNN for a Facebook ID, email::XXX@YYYY.com for a user's email address, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I had actually read the brewery example a while ago and not realized. So I was wondering if I had missed an issue with it.